# Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3205

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting this error while restoring the backup.

> Too many backup devices specified for backup or restore; only 64 are
>   allowed. RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 3205)

I have `.bak` file, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the restore statement you're using?

Comment: I have created the db and then right click on that db > tasks > restore > database.

Comment: While the error does not seem to indicate such, this is commonly seen when trying to restore a backup made on one version of SQL to a server running another version. What version of SQL is this backup from?

Comment: Why did you create an empty (?) database first? Why not just go to the database node in the object explorer > restore database? This might prevent an issue with the database compatibility level.

Comment: To @Mithrandir's point: Before you hit "OK" on the restore dialog, hit the "Script" button and show us the restore script it outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say, but you have a corrupt backup file.  If you can, backup the database again, but use the "with verify" option to ensure it is fully functional.